# Why is $6$ the multiplicative identity of the ring $2 \Bbb Z_{10}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Just wondering how you are able to determine that the multiplicative identity of the ring $2 \Bbb Z_{10}$ which is $\{ 0,2,4,6,8 \}$ is 6. I tried multiplying every element in this ring by 6, but I never got the original element for an answer with mod 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$6$ is the identity because

- $6 \times 0 = 0 \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$
- $6 \times 2 = 12 \equiv 2 \pmod {10}$
- $6 \times 4 = 24 \equiv 4 \pmod {10}$
- $6 \times 6 = 36 \equiv 6 \pmod {10}$
- $6 \times 8 = 48 \equiv 8 \pmod {10}$

I'm not sure where you might have gone wrong, maybe a miscalculation or a misunderstanding?

Comment: Thank you, as soon as i posted this i figured it out, i was thinking the answer would equal 6 each time instead of the element being multiplied by 6. It threw me off since I'm used to 1 usually being the identity.